# What is a strongly discrete sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, definition

The question is simple: What is the definition (and possibly examples or applications) of strongly discrete sequence? I have seen this term, but I am not able to find anything about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the usual definition is that a set $A$ in a topological space $X$ is strongly discrete if one can assign to each point $a\in A$ a neighborhood $N_a$ of $a$ such that, for any distinct $a,b\in A$, we have $N_a\cap N_b=\varnothing$.

("Discrete" without "strongly" is similar except that one only requires $b\notin N_a$ rather than $N_a\cap N_b=\varnothing$.  This is equivalent to saying that the subspace topology on $A$ is discrete.)